# Update Docker Container Without Dataloss

Tags: docker

I've docker-pulled an image, then ran a named container. How can I update that named container to the latest image?

And it would be perfect to not loos any data and not have to setup data directories and initialize and fill them with old data (just using current volumes).

Env: docker, Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I update that named container to the latest image?

That's not how docker is intended to be used.

Each image (and containers based on them) should be stateless. If the processes running in each container need to store state somewhere, it should be somewhere **outside** of that container. That could be in a RDBMS, a volume mount from the host filesystem, a docker volume, etc.

If you really want to do what you're asking, it's likely that you should not be using docker, as you will be guaranteed to spend more time making the tool do things that it's not meant to do than is appropriate.

---

After discussion in comments below, it was clarified that all you're asking is: does data in host-volume mounts get deleted along with containers. The answer to that is: no it does not.

Comment: State/Data is stored in a host directory. I just want to update safely (and easily if possible).

Comment: Well then what are you worried about? Kill the current container, then run the new one.

Comment: It also goes without saying that any time you are worried about losing data is a perfect opportunity to examine and test your backups.

Comment: :) You mean that I've just to `docker pull` then `docker run` (with proper parameters)? No worry about previous containers and images? Does deleting previous container deletes the data on the host directory (because of it's settings)?

Comment: No, deleting old containers will not delete anything on the host directories that were previously mounted into those containers.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer now. And if you please add this last part about data directories on host, to the answer. That would be awesome!